# How to debug METAPOST inlined in ConTeXt? (Or "message" primitive and "loggingall;" in inlined METAPOST)

Tags: luatex, context, metapost, metafun

I have a METAPOST program that works fine with mpost, but fails when I try to run it inline in ConTeXt. In order to debug it, I would like to see the usual METAPOST logging and/or to use the METAPOST "message" primitive.

However, whenever I add "loggingall;" or a message statement to my ConTeXt file, I encounter errors like this

```
metapost        > initializing instance 'metafun' using format 'metafun'
metapost        > loading 'metafun': D:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/metafun.mpiv
! terminal:
```

What is the appropriate way to debug problems with inline METAPOST code in ConTeXt?

My example file is:

```
\loggingall

\starttext
\framed{Hello world.}
This is a simple_test.

\startMPpage
loggingall;
fill fullcircle scaled 1in withcolor blue;
label.top(btex This is a test. etex, origin);
\stopMPpage

\stoptext
```

I am using TeXLive 2012 on Windows.

I apologize for any vagueness in this question. I’m not really sure how the various pieces fit together.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default MetaPost does not display the messages injected with `message`.
However, the messages can be enabled using `\enabletrackers`.

To enable verbose debug output use `tracingall`, which prints plenty of debugging output to the console and the log file. Here's a complete
example:

```
\enabletrackers
  [metapost.showlog]

\starttext
  \startMPpage
    tracingall;
    message "This is a debug message.";
    fill fullcircle scaled 1in withcolor blue;
    label.top(btex This is a test. etex, origin);
  \stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

Comment: that is only the default log and not really a debugging like `\loggingall`

Comment: that also gives also no metapost output. Compare it with a `mpost <file>.mp`

Comment: @Herbert On my system I get a 23K log file with plenty of info. The message shows up as well as all assignments. What exactly is missing?

Comment: I used the `context` from TL2012 and there are no infos about mpost in the logfile

Comment: @Herbert Confirmed, no log output on `2012.05.30 11:26`. It works with a current version `2013.02.19 19:38`.

Comment: I greatly appreciate this answer, but I would like to be able to have the metapost logging sent to the log (the TeX log is fine), but *not* to the screen.  When 'tracingonline=0;'

Comment: corrected text from previous comment:     I greatly appreciate this answer, but I would like to be able to have the metapost logging sent to the log (the TeX log is fine), but *not* to the screen.  When 'tracingonline=0;' is set, metapost run fails with a TeX error '<inserted text> ...lable:=true; ;;;;]===], false)}' somewhere in the processing of \meta_process_graphic.

Comment: I don't see the error you get. You have to set `tracingonline:=0` not `tracingonline=0`. However, after this setting it does not log to the log file any longer. Did you check if the error vanishes with a newer version? Apparently the logging mechanism changed between `2012.05.30` and `2013.02.19`.

Comment: Thanks, Marco.  (Again!)  Sorry for the typo.  I was indeed using assignment (:=).  I have not tried a newer version as I was unsure which newer thing to try.  That is, newer mplib, newer ConTeXt, or newer LuaTeX.  I've only used the pre-compiled binaries from TeXLive and from MiKTeX.  Do you have suggestions on where to start?

Comment: You can install [ConTeXt standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone) alongside TeXLive or MikTeX without interference. You can then use it for production or just for testing if a bug has been fixed in a newer version.

Comment: Thanks again, Marco.  I installed ConTeXt standalone and it is an improvement, but still not perfect.  Specifically, I can use "loggingall", but then have no visible output in my figure. Using my example code above, I even removed the label. statement.  When I run with just the "loggingall;" and the "fill fullcircle...", I get a blank page.  When I run without the "loggingall;", I see the blue circle.  Weird.  context version: 2013.02.20 14:35

Comment: Additional weirdness:  with just "tracingall;" and "fill fullcircle...", I see the blue circle.  With "tracingall; tracingonline := 0;" and the "fill fullcircle...", I see the blank page.

Comment: @ColinFraizer Same here, tracingall works, logginall produces an error. Sorry, can't help further. If this is important for you, consider approaching the MetaPost (or ConTeXt) mailing list.